# Jackson module not registered after update to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I'm as upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.21 to 2.2.5.

I need to use `MonetaryModule` to deserialize rest calls, and depending on Spring's `ObjectMapper`.

I have defined such a bean for this module in a some `@Configuration` class (`MonetaryModule` is extending `Module`):

```
@Bean
public MonetaryModule monetaryModule() {
    return new MonetaryModule();
}
```

I can see in `/beans` endpoint it was created. However, it is not actually loaded to `ObjectMapper`. After a lot of debugging and digging around Spring's code, I came to the conclusion that there is something wrong in `JacksonAutoConfiguration`. it has an inner static class called `JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration` and in it there's a `bean` that creates the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. in the creation process, there's a call to `customize()` that eventually gets to this code:

```
private void configureModules(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    Collection<Module> moduleBeans = getBeans(this.applicationContext, Module.class);
    builder.modulesToInstall(moduleBeans.toArray(new Module[0]));
}
```

This code seems responsible for loading the modules into `ObjectMapper`, Problem is that this `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` is not actually created. It appears in `/beans` endpoint but de facto when I breakpoint there I'm not hitting the breakpoint. This explains why the module is not loaded into `ObjectMapper`.

Question is, why is this code not being called? and why `/bean` indicates the bean does exist?

Edit - Adding conditions evaluation report:

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration#configServicePropertySource matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.RetryConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable', 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect', 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.fail-fast) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.RetryConfiguration#configServerRetryInterceptor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: configServerRetryInterceptor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesRebinder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false) did not find property 'proxy-target-class' (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.ClassProxyingConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)

   DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled) did not find property 'spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.RsaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Keystore nor key found in Environment (EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.KeyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.VanillaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None
```

Also, attached is the output of `/conditions` & `/beans` endpoints output (Too large to paste into the post itself)

[endpoints output](https://gofile.io/d/IWDtMd)

Comment: Any libray with its own autoconfiguration (...and creating Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...

Comment: Have you tried to debug the default constructor of Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder? (It should be possible at least in Intellij Idea and Eclipse seems to know that too according to some quick googling.)

Comment: CTOR of Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder is used (in my scenario) in MappingJackson2CborHttpMessageConverter which I debugged. It doesn't contain the needed module.

Comment: MappingJackson2CborHttpMessageConverter didn't exist before Spring Framework 5. Could you provide more information in your question? What does your web config setup looks like, in which codec and how you're expecting to use that module?

Comment: I didn't understand what codec you are talking about... The module is being used in the rest controller of the application to deserialize requests (JSON) containing a monetary amount. What do you want me to specify about the web config setup exactly (You must understand that it is a complex application with many configurations)? Also, in MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, I never get directly to the CTOR with params, only to the default one (which then calls the parameterized CTOR).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the message converter instead of codec (the reactive name for the same concept). There must be something else here. I've created a sample application with Zalando's `jackson-datatype-money` and the `MoneyModule` bean is picked up successfully. You'll probably need to create a sample application reproducing the problem so we can take a look.

Comment: I'm not using Zalando's ```jackson-datatype-money``` and not planning on using it. I'm just defining a bean of type ```MonetaryModule``` and expects it to be registered to ObjectMapper. I don't think I can reproduce the problem with a sample project since I assume the problem is not with spring but with some code of mine - which code? that's the million dollar question...

Comment: You can try and provide more information here (your main application class, application properties, WebMvcConfigurer custom classes, the auto-configuration report) or try and reproduce the problem in a small project you can share. Without any of those, we can't help you I'm afraid.

Comment: Added conditions evaluation report, hope this helps

Comment: Also added helpful endpoints (```/conditions``` & ```/beans```) outputs to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition evaluation report shows the following:

```
        "JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapper": {
          "notMatched": [
            {
              "condition": "OnBeanCondition",
              "message": "@ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' jacksonBuilder"
            }
          ],
          "matched": []
        },
```

This means that the Spring Boot auto-configuration condition is backing off since your application already provides an opinion on the matter: there is already an `ObjectMapper` bean named `jacksonBuilder`; it is provided by the application or some configuration class in a library you're using.

In this case, this comes from a configuration class, as pointed out by the beans endpoint:

```
        "jacksonBuilder": {
          "aliases": [],
          "scope": "singleton",
          "type": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper",
          "resource": "class path resource [com/behalf/core/authorization_domain/config/AuthorizationDomainConfiguration.class]",
          "dependencies": []
        },
```

You should here get in touch with the maintainers of this `AuthorizationDomainConfiguration` and let them know that they should avoid overriding the opinion of the application on JSON (de)serialization.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!